# Error in filtering error in compiling R markdown

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, r-markdown

I use the filter throughout my code but this one instance isn't working. I can't figure out why.

```
{sql Graduation, eval=FALSE, connection=con, include=FALSE, output.var= "AY1519_Grads"}
SELECT *
FROM  dm_prd_cers_student_completion
WHERE Year_Grad BETWEEN '2015' AND '2019' 
AND txt_program_code IN ('480501', '480508','150702')
AND txt_oe_indicator= 'OPEN'
```

```
{r GradbyYear.MachineTools, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

Mech_tool_grad <- AY1519_Grads %>% 
  filter(txt_program_code == "480501") %>% 
  group_by(txt_college_name, txt_degree_level_name, Year_Grad) %>% 
  summarise(Count=n(), .groups= "drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(Year_Grad, txt_degree_level_name), values_from= Count, values_fill=0) %>% 
  relocate(txt_college_name, `2015_Certificate < one year`, `2015_One year but < two year certificate`,`2015_Associate I creditable`, `2016_Certificate < one year`, `2016_One year but < two year certificate`,`2016_Associate I creditable`,`2017_Certificate < one year`, `2017_One year but < two year certificate`,`2017_Associate I creditable`,`2018_Certificate < one year`, `2018_One year but < two year certificate`, `2018_Associate I creditable`,`2019_Certificate < one year`, `2019_One year but < two year certificate`, `2019_Associate I creditable`)


kable(Mech_tool_grad, "latex", booktabs=T, align= "lccccccccccccccc", col.names= c("College", "Certificate", "Diploma","Associate's Degree", "Certificate", "Diploma", "Associate's Degree","Certificate", "Diploma", "Associate's Degree","Certificate", "Diploma","Associate's Degree", "Certificate", "Diploma","Associate's Degree"), caption= "\\textbf{Table 1} \\textit{Enrollment by year and Degree Level for Machine Tool Tech Majors}", row.names= F, escape=F) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down"), position = "left") %>% 
  row_spec(0, align = "c") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" "=1, "AY15-16"=3, "AY16-17"=3, "AY17-18"= 3, "AY18-19"=3, "AY19-20"= 3)) %>% 
  add_footnote(.,c("CERS Enrollment Table","Date Retreived: 3/29/2021"), notation= "symbol", escape=F)
```

here is the error

> Error in filter(., txt_program_code == "480501") : object 'AY1519_Grads' not found Calls:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html), Are you sure you are using the correct syntax for Rmarkdown and SQL?

````
```{sql, Graduation, eval=FALSE, connection=con, include=FALSE, output.var="AY1519_Grads"}
SELECT *
FROM  dm_prd_cers_student_completion
WHERE Year_Grad BETWEEN '2015' AND '2019' 
AND txt_program_code IN ('480501', '480508','150702')
AND txt_oe_indicator= 'OPEN`
```
````

noticed the `,` after sql and and the backticks

[image]